# How do I reference custom assemblies with scriptcs?

Tags: scriptcs

I have some custom DLLs that I want to reference in a script (stored on my HDD). I can see how I reference Nuget packages but I don't think it applies here.

How can I reference these assemblies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#r "..\bin\debug\test.dll"

a sample to point to a custom built assembly.
More Detail: https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/wiki/Writing-a-script

Comment: Thanks. I missed that bit.